# What is a Convenience Method in Java?

Tags: java, android

I am told that the Activity.findViewById(int) method  is a convenience method that calls View.findViewById(int) behind the scenes.

I am unable to find any documentation for explaining convenience methods wrt Java (I can see only iOS).

*PS : I am unable to find any answer  during my cursory Google search or via SO prev posts.If there is already one do point out so that I will close this one.*

Comment: What exactly is your question? What do you need explained?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A convenience method, in any language which has a concept of methods, is just that.  A method that makes things more convenient.

This usually means taking something that is complex or verbose, and making it more accessible.  Examples include pretty much everything in helper classes like `Collections` or `Arrays`.  As well as factory methods (to a certain extent, there are reasons for factories beyond simple convenience).

For a more formal definition from Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convenience_function):

> A convenience function is a non-essential subroutine in a programming
>   library or framework which is intended to ease commonly performed
>   tasks.